# Accessing and working with placeholders in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm very new to tensorflow. Currently, I have a neural network set up to solve an ODE (though the application isn't important). The code looks something like this

```
# Routine to train the neural network for solving -u'(x) = f(x)
def train_neural_network_batch(x_ph, predict=False):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x_ph)
    dpred = tf.gradients(prediction, x_ph)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square( tf.add(dpred,f_ph) ))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)
```

I use a batch stochastic gradient descent to train the network like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Train in each epoch with mini batch
    for epoch in range(hm_epochs):

        epoch_loss = 0
        for step in range(N//batch_size):
            for inputX, inputY in get_batch(x, y, batch_size):
                _, l = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={x_ph:inputX, y_ph:inputY})
                epoch_loss += l
            if epoch %10 == 0:
                print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)
```

The `get_batch` function is defined as follows:

```
# Feed batch data
def get_batch(inputX, inputY, batch_size):
    duration = len(inputX)
    for i in range(0,duration//batch_size):
        returnX = np.random.uniform(0,1,batch_size)

        # some function of x
        returnY = ...

        yield returnX, returnY
```

However, I am trying to do something quite complicated with my cost function now. In each batch returned by `get_batch`, I need to sample from an arbitrary number of subdomains, so let's say `returnX` is partitioned into N parts that will correspond to different parts of my cost function. In particular, I want to do something like this

```
for i in range(0,N):
    # compute the ith contribution to the cost function using [start:end] indices of the batch data
    cost += tf.reduce_mean( <some function of dpred[start:end]> )
```

I know that accessing a placeholder the way I have above makes no sense as placeholders are just that -- placeholders. But I hope the idea of what I'm trying to do is clear. The batch data returns a batch in partitions, and each of these partitions needs to be used in a different way to compute the cost function. So in forming my cost function, how can I access these different partitions given that they are just placeholders?

Edit: I've attached the full code below.

```
# Load modules
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special

######################################################################
# Routine to solve -u''(x) = f(x), u(0)=A, u'(0)=B 
######################################################################

# Create the arrays x and y, where x is a discretization of the domain (a,b) and y is the source term f(x)
N = 100
a = 0.0
b = 1.0
x = np.arange(a, b, (b-a)/N).reshape((N,1))
y = x

# Boundary conditions
A = 0.0
B = 0.0

# Define the number of neurons in each layer
n_nodes_hl1 = 40
n_nodes_hl2 = 40
n_nodes_hl3 = 40
n_nodes_hl4 = 40
n_nodes_hl5 = 40
n_nodes_hl6 = 40
n_nodes_hl7 = 40
n_nodes_hl8 = 40
n_nodes_hl9 = 40
n_nodes_hl10 = 40
n_nodes_hl11 = 40
n_nodes_hl12 = 40
n_nodes_hl13 = 40

# Define the number of outputs and the learning rate
n_classes = 1
learn_rate = 0.00004

# Define input / output placeholders
x_ph = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1],name='input')
y_ph = tf.placeholder('float')
w_ph = tf.placeholder('float')
phi_ph = tf.placeholder('float')

# Routine to compute the neural network (5 hidden layers)
def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h1',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((1,n_nodes_hl1))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h1',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h2',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl1,n_nodes_hl2))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h2',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h3',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl2,n_nodes_hl3))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h3',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_4_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h4',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl3,n_nodes_hl4))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h4',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_5_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h5',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl4,n_nodes_hl5))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h5',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_6_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h6',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl5,n_nodes_hl6))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h6',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_7_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h7',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl6,n_nodes_hl7))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h7',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_8_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h8',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl7,n_nodes_hl8))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h8',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_9_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h9',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl8,n_nodes_hl9))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h9',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_10_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h10',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl9,n_nodes_hl10))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h10',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_11_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h11',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl10,n_nodes_hl11))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h11',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_12_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h12',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl11,n_nodes_hl12))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h12',initial_value=0.0)}

    hidden_13_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_h13',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl12,n_nodes_hl13))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_h13',initial_value=0.0)}

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(name='w_o',initial_value=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((n_nodes_hl13,n_classes))),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(name='b_o',initial_value=0.0)}


    # (input_data * weights) + biases
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.tanh(l1)   

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.tanh(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.tanh(l3)

    l4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, hidden_4_layer['weights']), hidden_4_layer['biases'])
    l4 = tf.nn.tanh(l4)

    l5 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l4, hidden_5_layer['weights']), hidden_5_layer['biases'])
    l5 = tf.nn.tanh(l5)

    l6 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l5, hidden_6_layer['weights']), hidden_6_layer['biases'])
    l6 = tf.nn.tanh(l6)   

    l7 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l6, hidden_7_layer['weights']), hidden_7_layer['biases'])
    l7 = tf.nn.tanh(l7)

    l8 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l7, hidden_8_layer['weights']), hidden_8_layer['biases'])
    l8 = tf.nn.tanh(l8)

    l9 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l8, hidden_9_layer['weights']), hidden_9_layer['biases'])
    l9 = tf.nn.tanh(l9)

    l10 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l9, hidden_10_layer['weights']), hidden_10_layer['biases'])
    l10 = tf.nn.tanh(l10)

    l11 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l10, hidden_11_layer['weights']), hidden_11_layer['biases'])
    l11 = tf.nn.tanh(l11)

    l12 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l11, hidden_12_layer['weights']), hidden_12_layer['biases'])
    l12 = tf.nn.tanh(l12)   

    l13 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l12, hidden_13_layer['weights']), hidden_13_layer['biases'])
    l13 = tf.nn.relu(l13)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l13, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'], name='output')

    return output



batch_size = 16
nints = 2
h = 1.0/nints

# Feed batch data
def get_batch(inputX, inputY, batch_size):
    duration = len(inputX)
    for i in range(0,duration//batch_size):
        idx = i*batch_size + np.random.randint(0,10,(1))[0]

        # test points
        xTest = np.zeros([nints*batch_size+2,1])
        for j in range(0,nints):
            xTest[1+j*batch_size:j*batch_size+batch_size+1] = np.random.uniform(a+j*h,a+(j+1)*h,[batch_size,1])

        # append boundary points
        xTest[0] = a
        xTest[-1] = b

        # source term
        returnY = xTest

        # weights
        cost_weights = np.ones((nints*batch_size+2,1))
        cost_weights[0] = 0.0
        cost_weights[-1] = 0.0

        returnPhi = np.zeros([nints*batch_size+2,1])
        for j in range(0,nints*batch_size+2):
            if (xTest[j] < 0.5):
                returnPhi[j] = (xTest[j]-a)/h
            else:
                returnPhi[j] = (b-xTest[j])/h

        yield xTest, returnY, returnPhi, cost_weights


# Routine to train the neural network
def train_neural_network_batch(x_ph, predict=False):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x_ph)
    pred_dx = tf.gradients(prediction, x_ph)
    pred_dx2 = tf.gradients(tf.gradients(prediction, x_ph),x_ph)

    # initial residuals
    r = np.zeros([nints-1,1])

    # try computing with indexed placeholder as a test
    for i in range(0,nints-1):
        r[i] = tf.reduce_mean(y_ph[:, 1:2, :])

    # boundary terms
    cost += 20.0*((A-u[0])**2 + (B-u[-1])**2)/2.0

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)


    # cycles feed forward + backprop
    hm_epochs = 500

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Train in each epoch with the whole data
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):

            epoch_loss = 0
            for step in range(N//batch_size):
                for inputX, inputY, inputPhi, weights in get_batch(x, y, batch_size):
                    _, l = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={x_ph:inputX, y_ph:inputY, w_ph:weights, phi_ph:inputPhi})
                    epoch_loss += l
            if epoch %10 == 0:
                print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)


        # Predict a new input by adding a random number, to check whether the network has actually learned
        x_valid = x + 0.0*np.random.normal(scale=0.1,size=(1))
        return sess.run(tf.squeeze(prediction),{x_ph:x_valid}), x_valid


# Train network
tf.set_random_seed(42)
pred, time = train_neural_network_batch(x_ph)
mypred = pred.reshape(N,1)

u = mypred

# exact solution
ue = (x-x**3)/6.0


# Numerical solution vs. exact solution
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, u, label='NN solution')
plt.plot(time, ue, label='Exact solution')
plt.show()


fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, abs(u - ue))
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$|u_{N}(x) - u_{exact}(x)|$')
plt.title('Pointwise Error of NN Approx')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I can give it a try. First thing first, I assume that by partition you mean, for example, that if x has the shape `[_batch_, a, b]` and the partitions are along the 'a' axis, then elements `a_0` to `a_c` are the first partition, `a_{c+1}` to `a_d` are the second and so forth. Am I correct?

In this case you could just index your placeholder. This, corresponding to my above example and your code-snip, would look something like

```
tf.reduce_mean(some_function(x[:, i:i+c, :]))
```

Another question will be regarding the need to partition in first place. Can't you just make your model output the partitions as different variables? What does your model look like? Does this 'arbitary number of subdomain' stay constant per model or can it change for different iterations?

One last thing, if you're new to Tensorflow it might worth it to start with Tensorflow 2.0. They've changed quite a bit there and starting with it would prevent you having to learn both tf.v1 and tf.v2 in a short time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are correct about the partition. Why would the placeholder be indexed with `:` as the first and third indices? In any case, if I try something like that, I get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" and same if I just try something like x[i:i+c].

Comment: The `:` indexing means that these dimensions should be taken as is. Are you sure both `i` and `c` are integers? if you are my best guess would be that your exception is originated elsewhere. Could you post the exact code?

Comment: I attached the original code.It's a bit lengthy and complicated but the relevant part is in `train_neural_network_batch` where I just try to define a some quantities using an indexed placeholder.

Comment: Cheers, I'll start with a general comment. Instead of defining all the layers by yourself you can just call tf.keras.layers.Dense()(inp).

I have the feeling your exception comes from the assignment to r[i]. Can you run the the `reduce` function without any assignment of the result?

Comment: hmm, for some reason not assigning it seems to not cause any errors. I thought the result of the reduction would be a scalar that can be assigned as an entry of r. I guess that assumption is incorrect

Comment: Should be. But I guess that you have the exact location of your bug. I suggest you dive in with the debugger and have a deeper look at what's happening.